# OkHttpClient is not working inside Docker

Tags: java, docker, nginx, okhttp

I'm building server inside docker and trying to use OkHttpClient to get data but it seems not working.

When I test with postman, there is nothing logged in server log, but it shows 502 Bad gateway error on postman

[Nginx 502 Bad gateway error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTyX2.png).

My code is as below.

```
public String checkConnection(){
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
        log.debug("Build OkHttpClient");
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://example.com")
                .build();
        log.debug("Build Request");
        try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
            return response.body().string();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Update: Below code didn't work too.

```
public String checkRetro(){
        String url = "https://example.com";

        Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();
        builder = builder.url(url);
        log.debug("add url = " + builder);

        Request request = builder.build();
        log.debug("Build Request");

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().proxy(Proxy.NO_PROXY).build();
        log.debug("Build OkHttpClient");

        try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
            return response.body().string();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

**My environment**:

Docker

Nginx

Java 1.8

OkHttp-3.9.0

retrofit-2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Is the code you posted running inside docker? Did I understand correctly that you also have an api running in your docker container, that you then call with postman to verify, that your OkHttpClient succeeded?

Just a guess, if your setup is how I described it, there might be an issue with your docker container being reachable via your local network or the docker container is not configured correctly?

Comment: Yes, the upper code is running inside Docker but project structure is different from your guess. 
From API running in docker container, I called it with postman -> that API will create request to third party API and return response which got from third party API. It died when creating request to third party API .

Comment: Instead of OkHttp3, I created a method with httpUrlConnection and it worked fine so I think there is no problem with my Docker config.

Comment: Hmm you could debug and check if there's an exception that gets thrown. Maybe set a breakpoint in your catch block and check if there's an exception and what it's saying?

Comment: It is a jar file in docker container which built as server (containing many jar files). It seems very hard to debug. I will try then.

Comment: what about introducing a logger and write a couple of logging statements into your code  that give you some insight. You should be able to mount this logfile to your local filesystem

Comment: I added logs but they couldn't be reached, even the first log statement.
[ log.debug("add url = " + builder); ]

Comment: I found that maybe problem is my docker config. When sending request from my app, that is OK but due to nginx config, it couldn't recognize response from 3rd party server.